# How to Send JSON RPC in Java over websocket

Tags: java, json-rpc

In typescript we can send rpc notification like the below code

```
const webSocket = new WebSocket('ws://www.example.com/socketserver');
rpc.listen({
    webSocket,
    onConnection: (connection: rpc.MessageConnection) => {
        const notification = new rpc.NotificationType<string, void>('testNotification');
        connection.listen();
        connection.sendNotification(notification, 'Hello World');
    }
});
```

How to do the same thing in Java (Send JONSON-RPC message over websocket)?

I tried the below code in java

```
           String json = "[{\"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"result\": 19, \"id\": 1}]";
           JsonElement jsonElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);               
           session.getBasicRemote().sendObject(jsonElement);
```

But I counld able to catch that using the code below(Typescript)

```
rpc.listen({
    webSocket,
    onConnection: (rpcConnection: rpc.MessageConnection) => {
        const notification = new rpc.NotificationType<string, void>('onInitialize');
        rpcConnection.listen();
        rpcConnection.onNotification(notification,  (param: any) => {
            console.log("awa paams+ "+param); // This prints Hello World
        });

    },  
});
```

Comment: Did you already try anything? Do you have any code samples? Please look at the Stackoverflow "getting started" guide.

Comment: @RemcoBuddelmeijer I added my sample. can you answer me know